# Unable to deploy since port is occupied

Tags: docker, nginx, github-actions

I am trying to deploy via `Nginx` using `Dockerfile` and `Github Actions`.

Getting following error:

> Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address
> already in use.

I can deploy if I stop Nginx on my server.

But I am trying to deploy to Nginx, so server should be running.

What am I doing wrong?

My Dockerfile

```
FROM node:20-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json yarn.lock ./

RUN yarn

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8081

CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]
```

My Actions file

```
name: Deploy to DigitalOcean

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4.0.0

      - name: Set up Docker
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2.10.0

      - name: Login to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Build and push image to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v4.2.1
        with:
          context: .
          push: true
          tags: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}/example:${{ github.sha }}
          build-args: |
            NODE_VERSION=20

      - name: Deploy to DigitalOcean Droplet
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@v1.0.0
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.DROPLET_IP }}
          username: ${{ secrets.SSH_USERNAME }}
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
          port: 22
          script: |
            echo "Pulling Docker image..."
            docker pull ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}/example:${{ github.sha }}

            echo "Stopping and removing existing container (if it exists)..."
            if docker ps -a | grep -q "example-container"; then
              docker stop example-container
              docker rm example-container
            fi

            echo "Starting a new container..."
            docker run -d --name example-container -p 80:8081 ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}/example:${{ github.sha }}
```

My Nginx file at

> /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com

```
server {
        root /var/www/example.com/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Comment: I am not an Nginx expert. But it looks like you have configured the Nginx as a reserve prox (`proxy_pass http://localhost:8081`). You must start the docker container on 8081:8081.

Comment: @Bademeister That actually deployed fine cos not using the blocked port 80. But nothing on my domain. Getting 502 bad gateway when I hit the endpoint. And I know the / endpoint has a valid response when I try locally on my domain like https://example.com.